# Problem with Trigger after inserting Call

Tags: trigger

Logic: when we create call record then user in Accountmanager will automatically be added with Account Team of that Associated with Account.

I tried writing this but get error:Error    Error: Compile Error: Field is not writeable: AccountShare.UserOrGroupId at line 15 column 1

here is my code:

```
trigger insertaccountteam on Call__c (after insert) {
List<AccountTeamMember> atmlist=new List<AccountTeamMember>();
List<AccountShare> accsharelist=new List<AccountShare>();
if(trigger.isinsert){
for(Call__c c: Trigger.new)
{
if(c.Accountmanager__c!=null){
AccountTeamMember atm=new AccountTeamMember();
atm.Accountid=c.AccountName__c;
atm.teamMemberRole='Account Manager';
atm.UserId=c.Accountmanager__c;
atmlist.add(atm);

AccountShare sh=new AccountShare();
sh.UserOrGroupID=c.Accountmanager__c;
sh.AccountAccessLevel='Read only';
accsharelist.add(sh);
}
}
if(atmlist.!=null){
  insert atmlist;
  }
  if(accsharelist!=null && V.size()>0)
  List<Database.saveresult> sr=Database.isert(accsharelist,False);
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to fix the problem?

Comment: What is your OWD settings for Account. Also your code says `isert` is it insert or upset because if it is upset that could be the issue as it needs to be insert

Answer (score 2):

From the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf):

> UserOrGroupId
>
> **Type**
>
> reference
>
> **Properties**
>
> Filter, Group, Sort
>
> **Description**
>
> ID of the User or Group that has been given access to the Account. This field can't be updated

In essence, you can't specify this field when updating an AccountShare record. Its for reference only.

Additionally from the object reference under Usage:

> If you attempt to create an AccountShare record that matches an existing record, the request updates any modified fields and returns
>   the existing record.
>
> For example, the following code finds all accounts owned by a user and manually shares them to a portal user.

```
QueryResult result = conn.query("SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = '005D0000001LPFB'");
// Create a new AccountShare object
List<AccountShare> shares = new ArrayList<AccountShare>();
for (SObject rec : result.getRecords()) {
AccountShare share = new AccountShare();
share.setAccountId(rec.getId());
//Set the portal user Id to share the accounts with
share.setUserOrGroupId("003D000000QA8Tl");
share.setAccountAccessLevel("Edit");
share.setOpportunityAccessLevel("Read");
share.setCaseAccessLevel("Edit");
shares.add(share);
}
conn.create(shares.toArray(new AccountShare[shares.size()]));
```